# Try out ubuntu on thinkpad x40 (via usb)?

Tags: installation, wubi, thinkpad

I am trying to try out ubuntu (i,e, install it within windows) on my thinkpad x40. I followed the instructions on how to create a bootable usb (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download). No problem. The issue I have now is that th eusb ports on my x40 were burned before (common problem with the machine), i.e. do not work. So I got a USB notebook card from belkin. However it does not seem to recognize the usb stick from bios, thus I cannot boot from it. I also do not have a cd rom. Then tried to run wubi from the usb stick, briefly appears in task manager, no further action.

So I tried it with wubi.exe, but same thing. Downloaded it to desktop, run it, briefly appears in the task manager under processes, no further action.

Any one idea? I have enough memory and enough freed hd space.

Thanks.
Oliver

Answer (score 3):

If you have no means of booting via USB or CD-ROM, you may be able to use the boot rom on the network card.  Configuration is not trivial, but the following guide might help:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to put down $15 you can always buy a docking station for x40. They're quite cheap these days and having one will be quite useful if all the usb-ports are fried from your thinkpad. If you suspect that the whole usb system is fried you should get one with an optical drive included.

http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l2736&_nkw=X4+ultrabase